# How To Understand dynamic HTML in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to update a VB.NET Web Project done by someone else about 5 years ago using Visual Studio 2008.

The webform I am stumped on now has two (2) [ASP GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) controls, and I can't seem to tell how an [ImageButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is evaluating (or failing).

I need to fix the failing part!

Below is a [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control with the [ImageButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) `ibComplete` that is failing:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Font-Size="Small" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="25" OnRowCommand="gridview1_RowCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridview1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="gridview1_RowDataBound" runat="server" Visible="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="950px" BackColor="White" DataKeyNames="partid,primary_vendor,PART_DESCRIPTION,PRI_VENDOR_NAME,MIN_REORD_QTY,PUOM,Revised_Date">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
      <ItemStyle Width="30px" />
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="ibComplete" CommandName="Complete" Width="17px" Height="15px" ImageUrl="~/Images/uncheck.jpg" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderTemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lbaddAll" CommandName="AddAll" runat="server">All</asp:LinkButton>
    </HeaderTemplate>
  ...
```

OK, for the ImageButton ibComplete, I have set a breakpoint on the RowCommand:

```
Protected Sub gridview1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs)
  Try
    Dim GridView1 As GridView = CType(gvVendor.SelectedRow.FindControl("GridView1"), GridView)
    m_emp = m_master.Employee ' EmployeeManager.getEmployeeListByEmpLogin(empName.Trim)
    If e.CommandName = "Complete" Then
```

However, before it is ever hit, I have some odd looking "eval code" file that is throwing an error here:

```
_endPostBack: function PageRequestManager$_endPostBack(error, executor, data) {
    if (this._request === executor.get_webRequest()) {
        this._processingRequest = false;
        this._additionalInput = null;
        this._request = null;
    }

    var eventArgs = new Sys.WebForms.EndRequestEventArgs(error, data ? data.dataItems : {}, executor);
    Sys.Observer.raiseEvent(this, "endRequest", eventArgs);
    if (error && !eventArgs.get_errorHandled()) {
        throw error;
    }
},
```

The error, reported through the VS2008 GUI, is simply this:

> JavaScript runtime error:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Input string was not in a correct format.

[image: screenshot]

This code doesn't even exist in my document, and on the tab for it in VS2008, it is called **ScriptResource.a...cf8d3f2 [dynamic]**. It vanishes as soon as I stop my project, so I can't really edit any of it.

I realize this is very hard for most to understand, and that I'll likely need to include something else for someone to be able to answer me. That's fine! Just tell me what I need to include.

### How do I fix this error?

Comment: Only occurring in IE10?

Comment: Well, I have Google Chrome installed as well, but I can't get the menus to display at all in Chrome. I have IE10 on my machine, but the item that is supposed to populate on this `click event` isn't working on other machines - which is why I am having to work on it.

Comment: Chrome seems like an unrelated issue and those other machines could be running IE 10 too.  I would first check to see if this is an IE 10 specific problem as I ran into the same thing and had to install patches.

Comment: There are a number of workarounds and solutions, but I wouldn't even investigate until you confirm it's IE 10 only.

Comment: It is a moot point. These are work computers and policy dictates everyone use the same thing. If this is an IE10 issue, I need to know how to make the page compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely an issue with a change made in IE 10 that sends the coordinates of Image inputs in decimal format instead of as integers.

Some suggested fixes include:

1. Upgrading to the .Net 4.5 Framework
2. Setting compatibility mode to IE8/9

   meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"
3. Applying these patches:

.Net 4.0

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836939

.Net 2.0

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836943

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836942

The Bug Report URL is https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/755419/asp-net-4-0-and-ie10-click-on-imagebutton-in-updatepanel-produces-error-click-on-normal-button-does-not

Comment: If I am debugging this on my localhost, does the patch need to be applied on my machine?